# What does "take it to a point" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, verbs

This context comes from the movie "The Glass Onion" (**Don't worry No-Spoilers**)

LIONEL

*Will you please then explain it all
to us? Detective?*

BLANC

*No. I can peel back the layers, **I can
take it to a point**. But what lies at
the center... only one person can
tell us who killed .....*

Blanc's using an onion as a metaphor for the mystery that is taking place in the movie. I understand that you can peel back the layers. But what does "take it to a point: mean?

"take" verb

23. to remove: to take a coat from the closet.(Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context you provided is not enough to answer with certainty. I haven't seen the film.

It could be either

- I can understand it to a certain point. *(He can unravel the mystery up to a certain point)*
- I can [endure](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/take-it) (2) it to a certain point. *(Peeling an onion makes your eyes tear)*

Answer (score 2):

**Take** is a word with many meanings.  I think the appropriate definition is

> [17
> a
> : to undertake and make, do, or perform](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take)

Blanc is saying, "I can undertake this action (of peeling back the layers) up to a certain level (but not all the way to the center)."

It might also help to review the definition of ["up to a point"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up%20to%20a%20point).